# Azure container not installing modules for docker image

Tags: azure, docker, gotenberg

I am trying to use the [gotenberg](https://github.com/gotenberg/gotenberg) hosted in an Azure container so I can use it in my API which lives in the same VNET.

The exact image is: `gotenberg:gotenberg:7.9.1`
When I spin up the image locally, it lists a bunch of modules which gives me this output

```
2023-11-30 09:56:21   _____     __           __               
2023-11-30 09:56:21  / ___/__  / /____ ___  / /  ___ _______ _
2023-11-30 09:56:21 / (_ / _ \/ __/ -_) _ \/ _ \/ -_) __/ _ '/
2023-11-30 09:56:21 \___/\___/\__/\__/_//_/_.__/\__/_/  \_, / 
2023-11-30 09:56:21                                    /___/
2023-11-30 09:56:21 
2023-11-30 09:56:21 A Docker-powered stateless API for PDF files.
2023-11-30 09:56:21 Version: 7.9.1
2023-11-30 09:56:21 -------------------------------------------------------
2023-11-30 09:56:21 [SYSTEM] modules: api chromium gc libreoffice logging pdfcpu pdfengines pdftk prometheus qpdf uno uno-pdfengine webhook 
2023-11-30 09:56:21 [SYSTEM] gc: application started
2023-11-30 09:56:21 [SYSTEM] uno: long-running LibreOffice listener ready to start
2023-11-30 09:56:21 [SYSTEM] pdfengines: pdfcpu pdftk qpdf uno-pdfengine
2023-11-30 09:56:21 [SYSTEM] prometheus: collecting metrics
2023-11-30 09:56:21 [SYSTEM] api: server listening on port 3000
```

but when I use the same image in azure I get this:

```
2023-11-30T10:01:26.093954283Z 
2023-11-30T10:01:26.093991184Z   _____     __           __               
2023-11-30T10:01:26.093997084Z  / ___/__  / /____ ___  / /  ___ _______ _
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094001684Z / (_ / _ \/ __/ -_) _ \/ _ \/ -_) __/ _ '/
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094006084Z \___/\___/\__/\__/_//_/_.__/\__/_/  \_, / 
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094010484Z                                    /___/
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094014684Z 
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094018684Z A Docker-powered stateless API for PDF files.
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094022784Z Version: 7.9.1
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094026784Z -------------------------------------------------------
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094031084Z [SYSTEM] modules: api chromium gc libreoffice logging pdfcpu pdfengines pdftk prometheus qpdf uno uno-pdfengine webhook 
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094035784Z [SYSTEM] api: server listening on port 3000
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094039784Z [SYSTEM] gc: application started
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094043784Z [SYSTEM] prometheus: collecting metrics
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094047884Z [SYSTEM] uno: long-running LibreOffice listener ready to start
2023-11-30T10:01:26.094051984Z [SYSTEM] pdfengines: pdfcpu pdftk qpdf uno-pdfengine
2023-11-30T10:01:27.063956101Z {"level":"error","ts":1701338487.0636873,"logger":"api","msg":"code=404, message=Not Found","trace":"86e28eb6-26f9-4bbe-811b-ec41478b4770","remote_ip":"169.254.130.1","host":"169.254.130.6:3000","uri":"/robots933456.txt","method":"GET","path":"/robots933456.txt","referer":"","user_agent":"HealthCheck/1.0","status":404,"latency":49000,"latency_human":"49µs","bytes_in":0,"bytes_out":9}

2023-11-30T10:01:57.159232307Z {"level":"error","ts":1701338517.157984,"logger":"api","msg":"code=404, message=Not Found","trace":"20f579ec-4d93-410b-87b2-d430279f744c","remote_ip":"31.94.2.53:33795","host":"gotenberg2-3rmv2.azurewebsites.net","uri":"/","method":"GET","path":"/","referer":"https://gotenberg2-3rmv2.scm.azurewebsites.net/","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0","status":404,"latency":64901,"latency_human":"64.901µs","bytes_in":0,"bytes_out":9}

2023-11-30T10:02:05.181301882Z {"level":"error","ts":1701338525.181073,"logger":"api","msg":"code=404, message=Not Found","trace":"672ad314-1621-4ac4-874d-04d7823d0f98","remote_ip":"31.94.2.53:33795","host":"gotenberg2-3rmv2.azurewebsites.net","uri":"/","method":"GET","path":"/","referer":"https://gotenberg2-3rmv2.scm.azurewebsites.net/","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0","status":404,"latency":30101,"latency_human":"30.101µs","bytes_in":0,"bytes_out":9}
```

Hope someone can help with this limited information but it's all I have

Comment: The error messages you provided indicate that requests to certain endpoints (/robots933456.txt, /, etc.) are resulting in a 404 Not Found response from the Gotenberg API. This issue seems to be related to the URLs being accessed and is not directly related to the fact that Gotenberg is running in an Azure container. This could be due to a misconfiguration in your API.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. For some reason it's just randomly started working after 2 days....